# "not currently" vs "currently not"

Tags: word-order, style

Stack Exchange is testing [new close reason banners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow) and say:

> Closed. This question is opinion-based. It is not currently accepting answers.

I do not speak English natively but this sounds strange in my ears. Would it not be better to say:

> Closed. This question is opinion-based. It is currently not accepting answers.

or even

> Closed. This question is opinion-based. Currently it is not accepting answers.

Putting *currently* on either side of *not* does not feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some broad rules about the order in which multiple adverbs should appear in the same sentence. The adverb "*not*" is a little different because it negates *whatever comes after it*.

As an English speaker, I feel that "not currently accepting" best describes the *inactive state* of something, because everything is negated. "Currently not accepting" ultimately means the same, but it suggests that something *is* currently happening, even though it is nothing. A simpler way to think about this is that "not currently accepting" is the opposite of "currently accepting".

There is a more obvious difference between sentences such as:

> I am not watching anything on TV.
>   I am watching nothing on TV.

Even though "nothing" is the same as "not anything", by saying you *are* watching nothing it implies that you are perhaps watching nothing of note, rather than literally nothing. Although your example does not carry the same implication, hopefully, this explains why it seems more appropriate to negate the word "currently" as well. Your example could do without the word "currently" and still mean the same thing - that answers are not being accepted. It includes it, perhaps to imply that this could be a temporary situation, and, should it be reopened, answers may be accepted again.